# MVVM Binding not showing in view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

I am setting my data context in the code behind, and setting the bindings in the XAML.
Debugging reveals that my data context is being populated from my model, however this is not being reflected in my view.

Probably something simple but this has been troubling me for hours.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(MainWindowVM MainVM)
    {

        this.DataContext = MainVM;
        InitializeComponent(); 


    }
}

    public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand m_ButtonCommand;
    public User UserModel = new User();
    public DataAccess _DA = new DataAccess();

    public MainWindowVM(string email)
    {
        UserModel = _DA.GetUser(UserModel, email);
        //ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMessage));
    }
  }


public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _SurName;
    private string _Email;
    private string _ContactNo;

    private List<int> _allocatedLines;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
   }



 <Label Content="{Binding Path=FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,0,150,0"/>
```

Comment: Do you bind to `UserModel` anywhere?

Comment: Content="{Binding Path=UserModel.FirstName}" No?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting a `MainWindowVM` object as `DataContext`, which does not have a `FirstName` property.

If you want to bind to the firstname of the user, you need to specify the path `UserModel.FirstName`, as if you were accessing it in code.

So your binding should look like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=UserModel.FirstName}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0,0,150,0"/>
```

Additionally, you need to define `UserModel` as property instead of a field.

```
public User UserModel { get; set; } = new User();
```

Comment: i was trying that before, just tried it again and no luck

Comment: @DNKROZ do you see any error messages in the output window?

Comment: Ah yes i do BindingExpression path error: 'UserModel' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowVM'
However, UserModel is defined in MainWindowVM as public

Comment: @DNKROZ ohh, I see it now. You have to define it as property

Comment: Thankyou, just getting an error "Method must have a return type" do i need it set out like my other properties?

Comment: @DNKROZ yes, just like any other property. Ideally with a PropertyChanged event raising in the setter though.

Comment: Thanks i will give that a go now